# Connection between Haars measure Hilbertspace and Quantum mechanics.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lie-groups, quantum-mechanics, haar-measure

Iam a physics student,I don't have any background in measuring theory.
What I know is group theory and some priliminary basics of topology.
In a book by MV Altaisky I see[image: screen shot from the book of wave lets by MV Altaisky.]

I don't understand how he get expression 2.1and 2.2 and also I don't get how he connect it to famous quantum mechanical formulae 2.3.
Can any one please spend some of your valuable time to help me.
Thanks in advance.